# Return to a certain routine when an IF condition is not met

Tags: excel, vba

Facing an issue with coming up with a way to send back my code to a certain place when an IF condition is not met. In the code below, I have included an input box requiring data to be entered however through an IF condition I want to make sure atleast 8 digits are entered, If less than 8 digits are entered then I want to show a msg box "Error" and return to GL_Code position asking user to fill the inputbox again.

```
Dim GL_CY As Variant
Dim GL_Book As Workbook
GL_CY = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open GL", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
Set GL_Book = Application.Workbooks.Open(GL_CY)

'Filtering Range
Dim GL_Code As Variant, GL_Rng As range, GL_LR As Long
Dim GL_Sheet As Worksheet
Set GL_Sheet = GL_Book.Worksheets(1)
GL_LR = GL_Sheet.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter GL code to generate its activity ", Title:="Generate GL Activity", Type:=1)
   If VBA.IsError(GL_Code) Then
   GoTo ErrorHandle
   ElseIf Len(GL_Code) < 8 Then
    MsgBox "GL Code Not Entered", , "Error"
    'Return To GL_Code
    
   End If

Set GL_Rng = GL_Sheet.range("A4:R" & GL_LR).CurrentRegion.Offset(3, 0)
```

Relevant part of the issue is (Need a code for the commented part at the last line)

```
   GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter GL code to generate its activity ", Title:="Generate GL Activity", Type:=1)
   If VBA.IsError(GL_Code) Then
   GoTo ErrorHandle
   ElseIf Len(GL_Code) < 8 Then
    MsgBox "GL Code Not Entered", , "Error"
    'Return To GL_Code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naqi,

This should do the trick, at least it worked on my machine. I had to put a phony ErrorHandle label in as you didn't show that in your code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
  
   Dim GL_Code   As String
   Dim GoodEntry As Boolean
   
   GoodEntry = False
     
   Do
     GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter GL code to generate its activity ", Title:="Generate GL Activity", Type:=1)
     
     If (GL_Code = False) Then Exit Sub   'User pressed CANCEL!
         
     If VBA.IsError(GL_Code) Then
       GoTo ErrorHandle
     Else
     
       If Len(GL_Code) < 8 Then
         MsgBox "GL Code Not Entered", , "Error"
         'Return To GL_Code
       Else
         GoodEntry = True
       End If
       
     End If
     
   Loop Until GoodEntry
   
  ErrorHandle:
   
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks